# Is there such a thing as a "holomorphic continuation?"

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $f(x)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb C$. It is smooth in the sense that $\mathrm{Re}\,  f$ and $\mathrm{Im} \, f$ are both differentiable. I would like to be able to treat this function as if it were holomorphic, and so would like to "invent" a holomorphic function $g(x)$ so that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all real x, and with the values of $g(x)$ at complex $x$ being whatever it takes to make $g$ holomorphic. Is this possible for all smooth functions $f(x)$ as I have proposed? If not, when it is possible?

Comment: If such a continuation exists then $f$, seen a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, would be analytic as well. So smooth is clearly not enough, you should assume that $f$ is analytic.

\bar{But then, clearly, its radius of convergence is infinite and it's clear how to continue it to the whole plane.}

Comment: @Ayoub No, assuming $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb R$ does _not_ imply the radius of convergence is infinite! For example $f(t)=1/(t-i)$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Of course, you're right. Unfortunately, i can't edit my comment anymore. 

What's true though, is that it's possible to continue $f$ around a neighbourhood of the real axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does "differentiable" mean once differentiable, infinitely differentiable (smooth), or something else?

Your dream is not possible in general.  There are infinitely differentiable functions $\mathbf R \rightarrow \mathbf R$ that are not real-analytic.  Google "smooth non-analytic function".

In your case, let ${\rm Im } \, f = 0$ and let ${\rm Re } \, f$ be a smooth non-analytic function.